# How to search word in Array when clicking on button in Iphone

Tags: ios

I have database with 50,000 english words,on storyboard i have 26 buttons with alphabetic text(A,B,C.....).
So,when i click on any button first,then words that start from this letter will store in MutableArray and i want to search word in this array.If word is in array then message shows that you found word....
Problem is that Let I want to search word HelloAll,then pressing button with titletext 'H' store all words with starting letter 'H' in MutableArray from Databsase and searching starts in array on clicking next button,but when my text is on  point HELL alertview shows that YOU FOUND WORD because HELL word is also in this Mutablearray.

Comment: I think this will help you https://github.com/mikemthu/iOS-Word-Puzzle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to assume your Array is an string array:

```
NSString *word = @"HelloAll";

for(NSString *currentWord in Array)
{
   if([currentWord isEqualToString:word])
   {
      NSLog(@"Word found");
   }
}
```

with the isEqualToString method you check if the current string is exactly the same as the one you're comparing.